# SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

Estoy corriendo una aplicación en Expo y necesario registrarse.

La aplicación en Expo partiendo de una plantilla diseñada previamente.

La aplicación arranca perfectamente, pero es necesario registrarse y cuando hago el registro, me muestra estos errores.

Muestro los errores sin código, porque no sé cual es la parte del código  debo añadir para que puedan ayudarme.
Tengo el Backend en un servidor, también lo tengo conectado a Firebase.

Si pueden darme una idea de donde buscar los errores o que debo mostrar de mi aplicación para encontrar donde están los errores.
Pueden decirme que archivos debo mostrar para ver el error.
Gracias

```
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
- node_modules/expo/build/environment/react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
- node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:9:32 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal como comentas, hace falta fragementos de código para clarificar el problema. Sin embargo, debido a la naturaleza de lo que explicas, puedo deducir que dicho registro se realiza implementando algún cliente Rest que recibe un JSON desde su respectivo endpoint. A menudo, lo errores de API se manejan con texto HTML, si te está diciendo que el caracter no reconocido es `<`, probablemente se deba a que el texto retornado por la función/consulta sea de tipo HTML, XML o algún otro formato derivado. Fíjate en qué es lo que retorna la función al ejecutarse, antes de hacer la conversión

Comment: Gracias @KBeDev , pero no se por donde ir con lo que me dices. He añadido una captura de pantalla de el simulador a ver si orienta algo ya que código,  no se cualmostrar

Comment: Ya que desconozco la estructura/arquitectura de tu proyecto, lo único que te puedo recomendar es que realices un recorrido paso a paso de la funcionalidad. Ya que haces consultas el punto de partida debe estar definido en algún punto, de otra forma, no se ejecutaría dicha consulta. Ya sea al cargar un link o presionar un botón, la consulta debe ser delegada a algún componente. Puedes tomar de referencia [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64180882/expo-react-native-throws-json-parse-error-only-on-phone) pregunta (en inglés)

Comment: Agrega tu parser y la respuesta que vas a "parsear", el error indica que tu respuesta no es un JSON

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys , hay varios archivos parse, no se por donde empezar.